# Permissions Error in Heroku Postgres

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku

I'm getting the following error when trying to access my database via Heroku:

```
ProgrammingError: permission denied for relation posts_post
```

Some Googling has told me that I need to do something along the lines of

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLE posts_post TO <user name>
```

I tried doing that, using my heroku username, but it says that the role does not exist. Upon looking at all the users in the database (\du), they all seem to be hashes of some sort.

Does anyone know how to find the correct username to use? Is this the right way to go about fixing this ProgrammingError?

Answer (score 2):

Realized that I was getting this error because I had exceeded my limit for the free postgres plan. Upgraded to the $9/mo plan and it's working. I'll leave this here in case anyone else runs into the same issue.